How do I pin an image to the left or right edge of the screen?
I have an image with an aspect ratio similar to the iPhone 15. In my code I use NSLayoutConstraint for image with top, bottom, trailing, leading constraints  anchored for device screen sides and adjust the appearance of the image with scaleAspectFill. In this case, I see almost my entire image, regardless of the device. Even when I use the iPhone SE 1st generation, I lose small parts of the image on the left and right sides. But this is a small part (5% of the image) and that suits me. But when I use iPad I lose (30-40% of image) due to different aspect ratio compared to iPhone. So I want to be able to pin the image to the left or right side of the screen when using the iPad. Then I will lose part of the image on only one side. This is the best way for me. But if I try to use NSLayoutConstraint with top, bottom, trailing, leading constraints and adjust the appearance of the image with scaleAspectFill, my image is centered. How to pin an image to the left or right side for iPad?
the code:
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

var imageViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
var imageViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
var imageViewLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
var imageViewTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

imageViewTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
imageViewBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
imageViewLeadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
imageViewTrailingConstraint = imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
addConstraints([imageViewTopConstraint, imageViewBottomConstraint, imageViewLeadingConstraint, imageViewTrailingConstraint])



You need create container view for UIImageView and pin it to left or right in that container.

If the image itself has the same height of the imageView, you can just set the contentMode to achieve this. If not, just get rid of one of side constraints to make it stick to the other one.

@MojtabaHosseini I need to add height constraint for imageView like screen height? And remove trailing constraint for example?

@Cy-4AH Can you show an example in the answer? I don't really understand what difference this makes. I get same result with a view

We can do this by modifying the image view's .layer.contentsRect ...
Here is a sample UIImageView subclass that allows for left, center or right alignment:
class AlignedAspectFillImageView: UIImageView {
    
    enum Alignment {
        case left
        case center
        case right
    }
    
    var alignment: Alignment = .center { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if contentMode == .scaleAspectFill {
            guard let image = self.image else { return }
            
            let imageHeight = image.size.height
            let imageWidth = image.size.width
            let viewHeight = self.bounds.height
            let viewWidth = self.bounds.width
            
            // Calculate scale factor to fill the height of the view
            let scaleFactor = viewHeight / imageHeight
            
            // Calculate the new width of the image when scaled to fill height
            let scaledImageWidth = imageWidth * scaleFactor
            
            // If the scaled image width is greater than view width, adjust the frame
            if scaledImageWidth > viewWidth {
                var xOffset: CGFloat = 0
                
                switch alignment {
                case .left:
                    xOffset = 0
                case .right:
                    xOffset = 1 - (viewWidth / scaledImageWidth)
                case .center:
                    xOffset = (1 - (viewWidth / scaledImageWidth)) * 0.5
                }
                
                self.layer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: 0, width: viewWidth / scaledImageWidth, height: 1)
                
            } else {
                // If the image is smaller than the view even after scaling, center it
                self.layer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

and an example controller:

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var alignments: [AlignedAspectFillImageView.Alignment] = [
        .left, .center, .right
    ]

    let normalImageViewFit: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    let normalImageViewFill: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    let testImageView: AlignedAspectFillImageView = AlignedAspectFillImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "abc600x230") else { fatalError("Could not load image!!!") }
        
        for v in [normalImageViewFit, normalImageViewFill, testImageView] {
            v.clipsToBounds = true
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.image = img
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // so we can see the whole image
        normalImageViewFit.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // so we can see the "normal" aspectFill
        normalImageViewFill.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        // we want aspect fill for the custom image view
        testImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            normalImageViewFit.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            normalImageViewFit.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            normalImageViewFit.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            normalImageViewFit.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            
            normalImageViewFill.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: normalImageViewFit.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            normalImageViewFill.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            normalImageViewFill.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            normalImageViewFill.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),

            testImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: normalImageViewFill.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            testImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            
        ])
        
        // testImageView default alignment is .center
        //  so let's set it to .left
        cycleAlignment()
    }
    
    func cycleAlignment() {
        // cycle the alignments array
        let a = alignments.removeFirst()
        alignments.append(a)
        
        print("setting alignment to:", a)
        
        testImageView.alignment = a
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        cycleAlignment()
    }
    
}

We use this 600 x 230 image:

and we'll create three 240 x 160 image views:

top is set to .aspectFit so we can see the whole image
middle is set to .aspectFill so we can see the "normal" aspect fill
bottom is our custom class

Tapping anywhere will cycle the alignment of our custom class through left / center / right:



